# Transform Dictionary-Like Input to a Dictionary

Tags: python

How do I transform a dictionary input to a real dictionary that I can process?

When I execute an external command, this is what I get.

```
{'aaa': {'test_a': 0.11666666666667,
         'test_b': 1,
         'total_c': 0.11666666666667},
 'bbb': {'test_a': 32.883333333332999,
         'test_b': 1,
         'total_c': 0.11666666666667},
 'ccc': {'test_a': 11, 'test_b': 31, 'test'_c': 33}}
```

So, as you can see, the above is already a dictionary-format already. I was just thinking of doing something like.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import command
 result = commands.getoutput('<execute_external_command')
```

So that 'result' becomes a dictionary and I can just process it like any dictionary.

Comment: Is this from an API? As Lavrton's answer notes, this is probably JSON, which is technically not the same thing as a Python dictionary and might get you into trouble if you use eval on it (for example, it uses lowercase `true` and `false`, while Python uses uppercase). So the best solution is Lavrtons

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html Documentation is a great thing to read.

Comment: `eval` **will** "get you into trouble" anyway. It's a blatant security hole. Use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 4):

```
from simplejson import loads
result='{"name":"Anton"}'
dictionary=loads(result)
print dictionary

result="{'name':'Anton'}"
dictionary=loads(result.replace("'",'"'))
print dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("""{'aaa': {'test_a': 0.11666666666667,
...          'test_b': 1,
...          'total_c': 0.11666666666667},
...  'bbb': {'test_a': 32.883333333332999,
...          'test_b': 1,
...          'total_c': 0.11666666666667},
...  'ccc': {'test_a': 11, 'test_b': 31, 'test_c': 33}}""")
{'aaa': {'total_c': 0.11666666666667, 'test_b': 1, 'test_a': 0.11666666666667}, 'bbb': {'total_c': 0.11666666666667, 'test_b': 1, 'test_a': 32.883333333333}, 'ccc': {'test_c': 33, 'test_b': 31, 'test_a': 11}}
```